# Will this C recursive struct deallocate properly?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, free

Suppose I have a standard linked list struct as follows:

```
struct Linked {
    int data;
    Linked* next;
}
```

I make a bunch of them in a loop by `calloc`ing the `next` pointer enough memory to store another `Linked` and initializing it. As per the norm with linked lists, I only maintain a pointer to the first node as follows:

```
struct Linked *first = make_list();
```

Now, I want to deallocate the memory held by the entire list. Can I call

```
free(first);
```

and have it release all the memory (including the memory allocated to all the `next` pointers), or do I have to do the deallocation from the end backwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There has to be one call to `free()` for each call to `calloc()`. So, you need to use a loop to free every element of your list in turn. You can choose to do the freeing backwards or forwards, but you'll probably find that forwards is easier:

```
void freelist(struct Linked *head)
{
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct Linked *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Note (and this is important) that you must read the value of `head->next` *before* freeing the node.